# How to fix "IPad screenshots do not display the app in the correct device frame"?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, screenshot

I recently submitted a build of my iOS app for the **App Store**. But my build was `metadata Rejected`. The message from Review Team was

> Guideline 2.3.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We noticed that your screenshots do not sufficiently reflect your app
>   in use.
>
> Specifically, some of your 12.9-inch iPad screenshots do not display
>   the app in the correct device frame

The review team attached the following screen shots

**1. Screenshot 1**

[image]

**2. ScreenShot 2**

[image]

Can anybody tell me

1. What is wrong with these screen shots?
2. What does it mean?

> "your 12.9-inch iPad screenshots do not display  the app in the
>   correct device frame"

Comment: Might be the screen shots you uploading for preview does not matches with your app.

Comment: In your iPad screens, you have added screenshots of iPhone, It should be of an iPad.

Comment: Your screenshots for iPad show your app running on iPhone, in an iPhone frame. You should change your screenshots so that they use correct device to represent your app.

Comment: Run your app on 12.9-inch iPad device or Simulator and take screenshots and upload it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all for the contribution